# Get current time of webserver

Tags: php, time, web, webserver

I was wondering if it were possible to get the current time of a webserver.  So for example, I'd like to go on some arbitrary website, and get the current time of the webserver hosting the website.

If it makes a difference, I know some php, html and css.  And I know C++, though I doubt that'd help.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to get the time of the remote webserver that you have no control over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
print_r(get_headers("http://www.google.com"));
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 302 Found
    [1] => Location: http://www.google.co.nz/
    [2] => Cache-Control: private
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=099aa9ac8980212e:FF=0:TM=1329099372:LM=1329099372:S=E_PStXZJPIz2ZMm7; expires=Wed, 12-Feb-2014 02:16:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
    [5] => Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2012 02:16:12 GMT
    [6] => Server: gws
    [7] => Content-Length: 221
    [8] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [9] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    [10] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [11] => Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2012 02:16:13 GMT
    [12] => Expires: -1
    [13] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
    [14] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    [15] => Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=a4441cbc36cea461:FF=0:TM=1329099373:LM=1329099373:S=I6zlXb015nXUM0ht; expires=Wed, 12-Feb-2014 02:16:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.nz
    [16] => Set-Cookie: NID=56=22IthPMv3iR1hlwH0VkhSNq4imnzW4AhPoKM_3boXysAA-Zf4iM0u8Uv6EeV7coLnW91WQqGXyC9AtR4Snh9IG9kSfZRz8pk_X48VwV6UR0eY4c_UrtT8Wdk2zRyNcgR; expires=Tue, 14-Aug-2012 02:16:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.nz; HttpOnly
    [17] => P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
    [18] => Server: gws
    [19] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [20] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

)

i would not rely on it, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A website that I know, happens to change its content on a particular day, at a particular time (9:00AM).  I would like to know close to exactly when it's system clock hits 9:00AM, because it's clock may very from mine.

Comment: most server keep time accurately, mine use an atomic clock. I don't see the value in this, but you just use the above to get the Date... line.

Comment: At 6AM, my uni opens its timetabling system, and we get to choose our classes.  When this happens, hundreds of people attempt to access the server(s).  I would like to know exactly when they open it, so that I can try and get in first.  I was also thinking of using the Firefox addon (Check4Change).  If you have an suggestion, feel free to let me know.  Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: my suggestion is above. use the get_headers function

Answer (score 1):

Make a regular (HTTP) request to the server and see if it returns a date field in the response header. That *may* be in an adjusted timezone though, so while that would tell you whether the server's clock is set correctly, it doesn't tell you which timezone and hence time the server runs on internally. If the server doesn't return any such value, there's no real way to know.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the time can be obtained over HTTP - using the HTTP Time Protocol ([HTP](https://www.rkeene.org/oss/htp/)) which is available on many systems as [htpdate](https://github.com/iridium77/htpdate), though since it uses the HTTP Date header usually only has accuracy to the nearest 0.5 second (accuracy can be improved somewhat using multiple servers):

```
htpdate ntp.org
```

It is also possible to obtain the time using TLS (which extracts the timestamp from the TLS exchange) [tlsdate](https://github.com/ioerror/tlsdate) which can provide better accuracy:

```
tlsdate -nV ntp.org
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible allright and you won't need any programming to do it:

1. Install a HTTP Debugger like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and start it to monitor your HTTP traffic.
2. Visit the Web Page of the server you want to check.
3. Select the entry and take a look at the HTTP Response Headers, you're looking for the one called 'Date' which contains the local time as well as the time zone of the server.