# How can I get the time of a remote server?

Tags: php, time, server

I am currently working on a websever that will create a quick diagnose dashboard of other servers.

My requirement is to display the time of these remote servers, it seems that the NTP create some issues and I would like to see that.

I currently have a bat file on my desktop that simply send

```
net time \\SRV*******
```

I have also tried:

```
echo exec('net time \\\\SRV****');
```

=> result is '0'

But I would like to find a better solution in PHP so anybody of a team can read it on a webpage.

Any idea what I would do?

Note: this is not related to [How to get date and time from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621572/how-to-get-date-and-time-from-server) ad I want to get the time of a REMOTE server and not local server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get date and time from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621572/how-to-get-date-and-time-from-server)

Comment: @Veve this one is about time from a REMOTE server.

Comment: Which operating system is your webserver using?

Comment: @dognose my bad, vote retracted.

Comment: @waza_be : found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9254795/4074148) with `get_headers` of a webpage, in the case the remote server expose one.

Comment: Yes, I have also read that, but the remote servers are not webservers

Answer (score 1):

You can use NTP protocol to retrieve datetime from a remote server.

Try this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/...");

function query_time_server ($timeserver, $socket)
{
    $fp = fsockopen($timeserver,$socket,$err,$errstr,5);
        # parameters: server, socket, error code, error text, timeout
    if ($fp) {
        fputs($fp, "\n");
        $timevalue = fread($fp, 49);
        fclose($fp); # close the connection
    } else {
        $timevalue = " ";
    }

    $ret = array();
    $ret[] = $timevalue;
    $ret[] = $err;     # error code
    $ret[] = $errstr;  # error text
    return($ret);
}


$timeserver = "10.10.10.10"; #server IP or host
$timercvd = query_time_server($timeserver, 37);

//if no error from query_time_server
if (!$timercvd[1]) {
    $timevalue = bin2hex($timercvd[0]);
    $timevalue = abs(HexDec('7fffffff') - HexDec($timevalue) - HexDec('7fffffff'));
    $tmestamp = $timevalue - 2208988800; # convert to UNIX epoch time stamp
    $datum = date("Y-m-d (D) H:i:s",$tmestamp - date("Z",$tmestamp)); /* incl time zone offset */
    $doy = (date("z",$tmestamp)+1);

    echo "Time check from time server ",$timeserver," : [<font color=\"red\">",$timevalue,"</font>]";
    echo " (seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00.00).<br>\n";
    echo "The current date and universal time is ",$datum," UTC. ";
    echo "It is day ",$doy," of this year.<br>\n";
    echo "The unix epoch time stamp is $tmestamp.<br>\n";

    echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $tmestamp);
} else {
    echo "Unfortunately, the time server $timeserver could not be reached at this time. ";
    echo "$timercvd[1] $timercvd[2].<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: I think this would only work if every server is acting as ntp-server, which usually isn't true inside a local domain.

Comment: Servers have to be set to act as NTP servers - Windows configuration https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server, Linux (CentOS) configuration - http://www.tecmint.com/install-ntp-server-in-centos/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a powershell script along with WMI (assuming your servers are windows machines)

This will be way faster than the old `net time` style.

The script needs to be executed with a Domain-Admin (or any other user that has WMI-query permissions)

```
$servers = 'dc1', 'dc2', 'dhcp1', 'dhcp2', 'wsus', 'web', 'file', 'hyperv1', 'hyperv2'

ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    $time = "---"
    $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
    $server + ', ' + $time
}
```

You can achieve this with a scheduled task every 5 minutes.

If you want to display the time "with seconds / minutes" (I wouldn't query each server too often, as time does not change THAT fast), you could add a little maths:

When executing the script, don't store the actual time, but just the `offset` of each server, compared to your webservers time. (i.e. `+2.2112`, `-15.213`)

When your users are visiting the "dashboard" load these offsets and display the webservers current time +/- the offset per server. (Could be "outdated" by some microseconds then, but do you care?)

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

Just found that this is working:

```
echo exec('net time \\\\SRV****, $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```